# Failed to load plugin 'jest' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app/jest': Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'meta')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

[Here is a screenshot of the error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRABt.png)

This is what is in the package.json.

```
{
  "name": "********",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.10",
    "moment": "^2.29.2",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "react-hooks/exhanstive-deps": "off"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any way to solve this problem other than deleting "eslintConfig"?
I have looked at other articles regarding this error but could not understand it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your node_modules and install them again.

It seems like there is an underlying dependency which is missing.

Comment: I reinstalled the software again. Then a different error occurred.
-----------------------------------
package.json » eslint-config-react-app/jest#overrides[0]:  Environment key "jest/globals" is unknown
-----------------------------------
Editing eslintConfig in package.json resolves this error, but I don't know if I resolved it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

> **npm install**

again from the project folder, this fixed my issue